# Events are fired more than once when using Autofac

Tags: .net, winforms, autofac

I have Form which I registred using Autofac like that

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AssignableTo<Form>()
    .As<IMyForm, MyForm>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Everything works fine but when I added Load event to MyForm something bad was happend. If I opened MyForm first time load event is fired but if I opened it more than once load event is fired more than once too. To prevent that I added OnClosing method which looks like that

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    Load -= MyForm_Load;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would unregister the event in the `MyForm_Load` itself so you are more consistent. Also I don't think that your code is wrong.